# For loop to create multiple empty data frames gives error

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I wrote a for loop to create empty multiple data frames, using a vector of names, but even though it seemed really easy at start I got an error message : **Error in ID_names[i] <- data.frame() : replacement has length zero**

To  be more specific I' ll provide you with a reproducable example:

```
ID_names <- c("Athens","Rome","Barcelona","London","Paris","Madrid")

for(i in 1:length(ID_names){
ID_names[i] <- data.frame()
}
```

Do you have any idea why this is wrong? I would like to ask you not only provide a solution, but specify me why this for loop is wrong in order to avoid such kind of mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to store a dataframe in one element of a vector (`ID_names[i]`) which is not possible. You might want to create a list of empty dataframes and assign names to it which can be done using `replicate`.

```
ID_names <- c("Athens","Rome","Barcelona","London","Paris","Madrid")
list_data <- setNames(replicate(length(ID_names), data.frame()), ID_names)
```

However, very rarely such initialisation of empty dataframes will be useful. It ends up creating more confusion down the road. Depending on your actual use case there might be other better ways to handle this.